# adding rows to pandas dataframe within loop

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

There is a table that I have scraped from a site which I need to convert to a dataframe. Its html dom looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>value2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        ...
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        ...
```

I am using beautifulsoup to scrape the page:

```
table=soup.find('tbody')
for row  in soup.find_all('tr'):
    value=row.find('td')
    print(value.text)
```

I want to append this `value.text` to rows to a data frame including the `&nbsp;` values (as NaN).

this is a sample output of `print(value.text)`(the blank spaces represent `&nbsp;` values):

```
20Q4 FDLR WW Event Webinar 13 FixIssues - Didn't Attend
205
204
0
0.00%
1
0.49%
1
0.49%
179
87.75%
65
31.86%
3
1.47%
3
1.47%
3
 
4.62%
1
0.49%
1
0
0.00%
0
0.00%
0
```

The first  contains the headers of the table.
How do I go about doing so? Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `pd.read_html` function to convert the html into a dataframe. Here is how you do it:

```
import pandas as pd

table=soup.find('table') #Important thing to note: You have to provide the entire table to pd.read_html, not just the body of the table. Only then it would work.

dfs = pd.read_html(str(table))

df = dfs[0] #The output of pd.read_html is a list. In order to access your table (i.e the first and last element of the list), you can use dfs[0]
```